# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I tried insert ads using validation system but its give me error:

> `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, object given, called in D:\wamp\www\pagination\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 261`

**AdsController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file = new File($request->all());
        $file->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $validator = Validator::make($file->all(), [
         'category_id'=>['bail','required'],
         'titre' => ['bail', 'exclude_unless:category_id,1', 'required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
         'name' => ['bail', 'exclude_unless:category_id,2', 'required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
         'last' => ['bail', 'exclude_unless:category_id,1', 'required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
]);
      File::create($validator->validated());
        return Redirect::to("/")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

Comment: You should probably be passing `$request->all()` to the validator, not `$file->all()`.

Comment: Validate before you create a new instance of whatever model you want to make

Comment: @ceejayoz thx for u answer but its give me error `General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: Then `Auth::user()->id` is probably empty.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to pass `$request->all()` as the first argument to `Validator::make()`.

```
...

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

   /* validation rules */

];

...
```

And I think 'title' is misspelled in your validation rules (`titre`);

Comment: thx for u answer but its give me error `General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this errors comes when you use this:

```
    '$validator = Validator::make($request->all, [
        'file' => 'requeired|max:7000|mimes:xlsx,xls,csv'
            ]);'  instead of this $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
             'file' => 'requeired|max:7000|mimes:xlsx,xls,csv'
            ]);
```